# How to can chicken wings so that the bones are mostly soft

Tags: canning, chicken-wings

I am trying to figure out if it's worth my time to try to replicate a commercial dog food product, Merrick's [Wingaling](https://www.merrickpetcare.com/recipes/grain-free-wingaling-in-gravy/) wet dog food.

The important part is the chicken wings, which I assume are cooked in the can. They are clearly cooked and soft enough that they fall apart with a little bit of applied pressure (and therefore are too soft to splinter) but are still sturdy enough to be briefly handled.

(I put them in a Kong and it keeps my dog occupied for quite some time. He is pretty uninterested in the cubed chicken bits inside, which is one of the reasons I want to try to make "the good stuff" on my own. [Also, I think I can save some money doing it myself.] Now especially, it burns my biscuits to waste food and he is unresponsive when I show him how much this stuff costs.)

I understand that, as a low-acid food, [chicken must be canned under pressure](https://hgic.clemson.edu/factsheet/canning-foods-the-ph-factor/). However, most of my research shows results for human consumption, like these [hot wings](https://www.reddit.com/r/Canning/comments/xsxqh/canned_hot_wings_experiment_5_pints/). Nobody is talking about the bones, which I understand.

So then, the question is, how can I can chicken wings at home so that the bones are mostly soft?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, so one [person on reddit has done](https://www.reddit.com/r/Canning/comments/lhqhel/canning_chicken_thighs_for_soft_bones/) (almost) what you want and provides details (thighs, not wings.) They used 10 lb steam for 2 hours and 15 minutes. Altitude not specified. They did not get what they wanted at 1 hour 15 minutes.

Comment: Fish-specific, but detailed and notes that increasing pressure (thus temperature) increases the softening effect, so for home canners / cookers capable of it, 15 PSI might be better or faster. https://spo.nmfs.noaa.gov/sites/default/files/pdf-content/MFR/mfr503/mfr5031.pdf